# Cluster aware golang driver for YugabyteDB YSQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

There's a cluster topology-aware JDBC driver for YugabyteDB; however, is there one for Go? This seems like just plain GORM, which afaik would require a load balancer in front of the cluster: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/integrations/gorm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a page to build a Go app with [YugabyteDB-PGX](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/yugabyte/pgx) driver: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/quick-start/build-apps/go/ysql-yb-pgx/

If it is helpful, this was a tech talk from February on the general topic of Postgres-compatible Smart Drivers for YugabyteDB: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbXrRdB_4u0